# Zend 2 - Multiple aplication on the same server

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am developing a system that will be used for several companies, using Zend Framework 2. What is the best way to share the application between different companies?

Initially, I thought I could differ companies by subdomain, something like http://companyname.system.com, and use that to determine the settings (name, database, license files, email accounts, etc.) . But how can I do this, and use the same application?

Another option is letting all login in the same environment, and differentiate by the database, an ID field in User Table ... Is this a good approach? How should I deal with differences and particularities between different companies, in this case?

Anyway .. I need someone who can enlighten me.. Can someone there help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all the depends on the application. How much of it will be shared, will client websites have the same theme, will they have similar database data/structure, can your hosting handle the load, etc. Lots of stuff, so there's too much to take into account to give a definite answer.

Anyway you can make use of stuff like:

- using subdomains in routing : [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-hostname)
- using app specific configuration based on domain, e.g. you could check the subdomain name in `getConfig` method and load a domain specific config there (or merge it to other configs) -- so you could have different db configs this way. Or you could use the [abstract db adapter](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/zend-framework-2-multiple-named-db-adapter-instances-using-adapters-subkey/) and name your db adapters like your clients (would not recommend that though)

My experience says that it'll probably make sense to put functionality into modules that'll use to compose applications and build lightweight apps using these modules. The modules do all the hard work and the app is left mostly with bootstrapping the application and routing.